# Le aspect or modal particle

Tags: particles, aspect

In the sentence “即使在教室，他们仍然保留了自由散漫的天性”, is 了 an aspect particle or a modal particle? I thought that the modal particle needed to be at the end of the sentence, but I’m not sure why it would be an aspect particle in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Here, 了 is an **aspect particle** placed directly after the verb "保留" (maintain/retain) to indicate the completion of the action and change of tense.

- 他们仍然**保留了**... they neverthelessly (have) **maintained/retained**....